# How to access component in nested directory in ember app kit template

Tags: ember.js, components, handlebars.js, ember-app-kit

I have a component in /components/some-dir/some-component.js and am trying to use it in a .hbs template file.

```
{{#some-dir/some-component set=this}}{{/some-dir/some-component}}
```

but handlebars throws an error.
The ember app kit [documentation](http://iamstef.net/ember-app-kit/guides/naming-conventions.html) says that '/' gets converted over to '.' and to use an alias:

```
// controller/posts.js
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['posts/details'],
    postsDetails: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.posts/details')
});

// templates/posts.hbs
// because {{controllers.posts/details.count}} does not work
{{postsDetails.count}}
```

but was having trouble getting it to work similarly with a component, so didn't know if it applied or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As "answered" by stefanpenner in EAK [Issue542](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit/issues/542)

> "for now, just don't use sub-dirs rather just many more dashes (hopefully we can resolve this within htmlbars/handlebars)" ~stefanpenner